# Why "?v=hash" is added to my URLs?

Tags: urls, parameter

I'm new to wordpress, I set up everything, but there's something that bothers me: on every single URL or link, there's a "?v=hash" appended everywhere (example.com/?v=d21feabed96b).

I tried to see inspect every plugin, I don't understand how this parameter is added.

It looks like it's added in js, because if I see the source, there's no trace of this hash, but I can see in firebug live source.

Plugins installed:

- jetpack
- sumome
- wp-piwik
- wp super cache
- woocommerce

Theme: Storefront

I tried to disable everything, but still I get this hash, does anyone knows how and why it's added?

I'm also using cloudflare

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, what theme are you using?

Comment: Storefront by woothemes (and woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I thought is was something my new server was doing for the DEV copy of my site on a DEV server (using same url, accessed by changing my hosts file).  It's been driving me nuts.  Thanks to the answers, I now know it's caused by a WooCommerce setting I'd changed on the Dev server (as I change my shopping cart over to WooCommerce from WP EasyCart!  Indeed, it's wordpress related after all, but with so many services I use for my website, I had no idea where in the stack it originated.  I did not consider it was wordpress (plugin) related at all! ;-)  So, Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It was woocommerce, it has a setting "geolocalize users with cache support" which adds this parameter to every single url and link. I noticed that the hash appended was the same in every browser on my computer, so I realized it wasn't a "session" hash, but an IP address hash.

Comment: It was at "woocommerce->Settings->General->Default Customer Location", pick the third option, which is IP without cache.

Comment: I have the same problem and never had WooCommerce installed...

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I was wondering why the hash never changed on my laptop