# Why my URL has an unknown character string?

Tags: urls, site-url

I'm working on a WordPress website which contains an unknown string of characters behind the actual URL (/?v=11aedd0e4327). I've tried deactivating all the plugins, but nothing changed. I've also tried changing my permalinks settings, no success.

It's the first time a such thing happens, and I have to admit I really don't know where it comes from. Here is the link to the website : [My website](http://devmode.mr-zamal.com).

Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204937/why-v-hash-is-added-to-my-urls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "?v=hash" is added to my URLs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204937/why-v-hash-is-added-to-my-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, problem solved !

It was in the Woocommerce general settings "Default customer address". Had it set up on "geolocalize users with cache support". Just changed it and v=hash disappeared.